Replacing Info.plist placeholder
I have a .NET 7 MAUI project and require two versions of Info.plist: one for 'Debug', and another for 'Release'. The difference between both Info.plist variations are two values:
// Info.plist
<!-- Debug config -->
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foo.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <string>true</string> <!-- Difference -->
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <string>false</string> <!-- Difference -->
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>

<!-- Release config -->
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foo.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <string>false</string> <!-- Difference -->
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <string>true</string> <!-- Difference -->
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>

I decided to use myapp.csproj to replace just these two strings based off the configuration value
// Info.plist
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foo.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <string>$(NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads)</string>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <string>$(NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy)</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>


// myapp.csproj
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads>true</NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads>
    <NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy>false</NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads>false</NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads>
    <NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy>true</NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy>
</PropertyGroup>

I build my project via command line: dotnet build --verbosity diagnostic > build-log.txt. Upon examining my build logs, I do see that the placeholder values get replaced:
// build-log.txt
Initial Properties:
    __DisableWorkloadResolverSentinelPath = /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.410/DisableWorkloadResolver.sentinel
    __WindowsAppSdkDefaultImageIncludes = **/*.png;**/*.bmp;**/*.jpg;**/*.dds;**/*.tif;**/*.tga;**/*.gif
    _abslId = absl
    _AggressiveAttributeTrimming = t
    ...
    NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads = true
    NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false
    ...

However, when I examine the packaged up Plist.info (/bin/Debug/net7.0-ios/iossimulator-x64/myapp , Info.plist), I still see my placeholder values there:
// Info.plist inside the packaged myapp
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foo.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <string>$(NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads)</string>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <string>$(NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy)</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>

I'm wondering if I'm mis-interpreting my logs, or if I'm somehow mis-examining the built Info.plist, or of I'm doing something incorrect to replace my placeholder values?
